# Python socket not processing all commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have been working on implementing a UDP socket program (basically a server/client type idea). I have come across a problem where when the server gets a message from the client, follows the code to a point, but then stops, and next time the server is hit with another message from the client, it finishes processing the commands from the previous request, then stops again, and repeats. This might not make sense but I will try explain with code.

```
def receive():
    conn_list = connections()
    routes = []
    sender = -1
    read, write, errors= select.select(conn_list,[],[])
    data = None
    for sock in read:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        print("hello")

def run():
    filename = input("fielname? ")
    route_table = create_table(filename)
    while True:
        receive()
```

The message is `"2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]"` (for example)
so the expected result in the console each time the server is hit would be:

```
    2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]
    hello
```

However, the first time it is run, I get:

```
    2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]
```

then the second time, I get:

```
    hello
    2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]
```

so the entire console after hitting the server twice looks like this:

```
    2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]
    hello
    2. 2. 5. 15000. [4, 2]. [6, 1]
```

Thanks in advance for the help if anyone has any ideas!

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to tell what's happening from this code snippet as there are many inconsistencies, but in Python commands like read, recv are blocking until (in your case) either 1024 bytes are read or the socket is closed. It's probable that blocking is what is causing the behaviour that you are seeing.

I suspect that you don't want to close the socket after every send.

In that case, may I recommend you try the following:

- Flush the socket on send to ensure that there is no buffering

  ```
  fd.flush()
  ```
- Use 'readline' instead of read - this should be non blocking provided there is a 'new line' in the data stream *or* if the exact data size is known on the send, use a value for read/recv less than 1024...

  ```
  data = fd.readline()

  data = sock.recvfrom(10)
  ```

Comment: 'The return value is a bytes object representing the data received. The *maximum* amount of data to be received at once is specified by bufsize.'

Comment: ? If we are trying to prevent blocking behaviour then using the correct sized  buffer will help ensure that either it is full so that read returns.. otherwise the call might wait until the entire buffer is full before return (which is exacerbated if the buffer is too large)